Do Jim's Magic Missiles strike simultaneously? If not, how is damage resolved?
This question asks about a source of advantage to combine with Jim's Magic Missile spell, with the requirement being that each of the missile attacks will have advantage.  A since-deleted answer suggested having a familiar take the Help action, but this comment pointed out that Help would give advantage to only the first attack, not all of them (which presumably was the reason the answer was deleted).
In thinking about the "first attack", I realized that it is not clear to me from the spell description when the missiles strike, and whether there would be a "first" attack.  It is well-established that the PHB magic missiles all hit at the same time, because the spell description itself says:

The darts all strike simultaneously

Jim's spell contains no such explicit statement, so we might surmise that each attack is rolled separately and resolves sequentially, much like the PHB versions of eldritch blast or scorching ray.
On the other hand, Jim's says:

If the attack roll for any missile is a 1, all missiles miss their targets and blow up in your face, dealing 1 force damage per missile to you.

If any missile rolls a 1, "all missiles" miss their targets - not 'all remaining missiles' or 'all missiles which have not yet resolved'.
So how is this supposed to work?
(1) Attacks are made simultaneously and thus damage is not resolved until all attacks have been checked for critical failure.
(2) Attacks are made sequentially, but initially only attack rolls are made, departing from the normal process of making an attack.  Damage is not resolved for any attack until all attacks have been checked for critical failure.
(3) Attacks are made sequentially, and damage is applied after each successful attack as usual for making an attack.  However, if a subsequent attack roll is a 1N, then previous attacks retroactively miss and have their damage removed.
(4) Attacks are made sequentially, and damage is applied after each successful attack as usual for making an attack.  If any attack roll is a 1N, only that attack and subsequent attacks "blow up in your face", while previous attacks are unaffected.
I would prefer a RAW answer, but if one is not available I will accept as RAI an example of actual use in game from the Acquisitions Incorporated video series.

Sage advice provides guidance in this case
The SAC contains the following entry:

When casting a spell that affects multiple targets, such as scorching ray or eldritch blast , do I fire one ray or beam, determine the result, and fire again? Or do I have to choose all the targets before making any attack rolls?
Even though the duration of each of these spells is instantaneous, you choose the targets and resolve the attacks consecutively, not all at once. If you want, you can declare all your targets before making any attacks, but you would still roll separately for each attack (and damage, if appropriate).

Therefore, all Jim's missiles strike simultaneously even if it is not stated on the description, but due to the particular effect of a critical failure it seems fit to roll the attack rolls and check for any 1s: in case there is one, the missiles explode and all them miss. Otherwise, roll for damage. So, option (2).
A table can roll one attack at time and backtrack if a 1 on the D20 happens, but it seems quite confusing.

+1. This is the option that makes the most sense, especially since there is no mechanic in 5e (as far as I know) where you have to go back and "retcon" the result of an attack or other event.

Good find on the SAC.

@Matthieu In general, no.  The shield spell, though, by converting what was a hit into a miss, can force such retconning.  Cf. Does blocking an attack with the Shield spell still trigger Armor of Agathys?, Shield spell - removing the special effects of a hit, Shield Spell and triggering effects of damage not taken

I'm not sure I understand your conclusion, though - the SAC says "resolve the attacks consecutively, not all at once" and you say "all Jim's missiles strike simultaneously".  What if I want to see if a missile hits or misses (a normal miss, not a crit fail) before assigning the target of the next missile?  SAC says I don't have to declare all my targets at once, but if the missiles all strike at the same time, how would I (within the narrative) make decisions about subsequent targets based on prior attacks?

@Kirt As a basis of combat, it is assumed that the whole combat round happens simultaneously, as in, every action of every character. handing it in sequence is just a means to make it digestible for our human brains and not require writing down all commands/actions and then executing all of them as a calculator without any further choices like in some wargames (Full-Trhust, X-Wing)

@Trish I think the "simultaneous combat round" means that each character is acting at the same time, not taking objective turns and then waiting for others.  I don't think it means that everything that one PC does on their turn happens at the same time - if I need to move to a foe before I am in melee range, that movement has to occur before the attack.

@Matthieu in addition to Kirt's reply, there's also the Atlas of Endless Horizons (pg. 120 TCE) that allows you to teleport 10 feet when struck by an attack- if your new location isn't in reach of the original attack that hit you, it misses instead.

@Kirt I think it is quite simple: roll the D20s, see if there is any 1: if not, resolve each attack consequently, In anyway your table resolve them (declaring each target at the beginning, see if the first missile hits the target).

@Eddymage I think I see - so all the d20's are rolled at once because the missiles hit simultaneously, but then assuming no 1N each attack is resolved consecutively.  I guess the problem I have with that is that the player gets to see all the rolls before assigning them to targets.  Can they choose the order in which to apply the rolls, then?

@Kirt exactly. Yes, I think that the order should be chosen by the player, per the XGTE rule.
